# Windows WPF elements do not show

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, frame

Why do I see one thing in design mode and another during runtime?

---

On a Wpf Program one of my pages looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="pPP_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pPP_2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1080" Width="1920"
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        WindowState="Normal"

    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
    <Grid x:Name="MainWindowGrid">
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="Pages" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Background="Transparent"/>
            <Button x:Name="start" Background="LightGreen" Content="Simulation Starten" FontSize="20" Click="Go" Margin="710,394,710,508"/>
            <Button x:Name="factoryManage" Background="LightGreen" Content="Fabrik Verwalten" FontSize="20" Click="ManageFactory" Visibility="Visible" Margin="710,590,710,317"/>
            <Button Background="LightYellow" Content="Back" Margin="1550,55,219,968" BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Click="backButton" Width="auto"/>
            <Button Background="LightYellow" Content="Exit" Margin="1701,55,68,967" BorderThickness="4,4,4,4" Click="Exit" Width="auto"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Description" Margin="72,44,1610,956" Text="kp-cpps-sim2k19" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Resources>
            </TextBox>
            <Button Content="Zurück zur Startseite" Margin="748,53,748,966" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
            <Button x:Name="Inventory" Content="Inventar" Margin="48,925,1586,52" Click="InventarClick"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Picture**

[image: Image Link]

Why during runtime does the window just goes all white with nothing being shown?

Comment: This might be due to your screen size, try dragging the corner of the app(while it's running)  to make the app window much bigger and see what happens. in that, case you may want to research how to use the grid correctly [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/)

Comment: A general note. Besides that two nested Grids are redundant, you are not using the Grid element as intended. Instead of putting all child elements in a single Grid cell and positioning them by Margins, you should define rows and colums by setting the Grid's RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions and put child elements in the desired cells by setting their `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your page size is large `Height="1080" Width="1920"`. You have zoomed out the window in the design view that is why you can see the whole window, but when you run it. When you resize it and you have set big margin values for THE buttons and others. Try to use grid properly with row and column definition.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outlandish margins such as `Margin="72,44,1610,956"` and place controls via grid rows/columns which will size accordingly to window height/width based on screen size.